# AutoCompleteTextView: dropdown list is only shown once

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've follow google tutorial for AutoComplete TextView. this is my code:

`xml`

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hint="my hint" />
```

`java` code

```
 private String[] list = { "word1", "word2", "word3" };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_fragment, container, false);

        description = (AutoCompleteTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.description);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
        description.setAdapter(adapter);


        return view;
```

So `dropdown list` with suggestions appears `only once,` but i want that appear `each time` first characters of `words write inside view match` with list element.

Comment: **dropdown list with suggestions appears only once** what it means?? can you explain clearly with some example..

Comment: i would write (for example) this string: "word1 and word2" inside view.
when i type "wo", complete suggestion list appear, so i tap on "word1" and text is insert inside view. Now when i type again "wo" for insert "word2" suggestions list doest not appear again.

Comment: ok..have you deleted the Word1 when typing for the Word2 or word1 is there.that means are you appeneding text like word1wo..

Comment: i would type "word1 and word2" string. When i type again "wo" (so in my textview theres "word1 and " string) no suggestion appear. It seems that i can use suggetsion only once

Comment: Yes.AutoCompleteTextView is only for slecting one Word form lultiple words..If you want for multiple words you need to use MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Comment: @kalyanpvs you should write this as an answer. So that the OP can validate it as "question solved".

Answer (score 0):

To get the suggestion again put a comma(,) after you selected a n option form the suggestion and type searching it again. Example type `"wo"` and choose form the dropdown and put a comma `(word1,)` and start typing again `(word1,wo)` now it should list you the options.

This is because the `Autocomplete uses comma(,) as the delimiter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MultiAutoComplete Edit text instead of the AutoComplete, this way, the list will appear with every word you write the edit text.

AutocompleteTextView only offers suggestions about the whole sentence and MultiAutoCompleteTextView offers suggestions for every token in the sentence. You can specify what is the delimiter between tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView and set the tokenizer as comma type

```
autoComplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```